# Curve fitting: How to identify the appropriate function for a beat-like phenomena?

Tags: trigonometry, plane-curves, curves, data-analysis

[image: A sample of the time series data]

I have a time series data which shows some beat like behaviour. The envelope does not look exponentially decreasing, as it is impossible from a physics point of view. The envelope is likely to be a periodic function with a large period. Also, there seems to be a mean linear or quadratic trend. Given these, which is the appropriate function for curve fitting?

Comment: your model seems to be : $f(n) \approx an+b + \sum_{k=1}^K A_k e^{i \omega_k n}$. since $a$ is small compared to $\sum_{k=1}^K i \omega_k A_k e^{i \omega_k n}$ you could use a derivative filter (the simplest is $g(n) = f(n)-f(n-1)$), use the discrete Fourier transform on $g(n)$ to estimate the  parameters of the sines  (the $\omega_k,A_k$) and $a$, and finally estimate $b$.

Comment: once you have the model, you can also use what I wrote to estimate a first guess for the parameters, and then use the gradient descent to get some better and better estimation.  here in my model the critical parameter is $K$ : unfortunately there is no perfect way to estimate it, and trying different values and choosing the one giving the "best result" is often necessary (and when $K$ is too large, you'll get for sure some sort of overfitting)